# Insufficient ldap access while all access is good in symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony5

I cannot make modifications to an ldap directory with symfony 5.4 with the Symfony Ldap library;

I connect in ldaps, reading no problem, but when I want to modify I get this error:

`Could not update entry "*group dn*": Insufficient access`

Although I have modification rights

The code:

```
$this->ldap->bind($_ENV['LDAP_USER'], $_ENV["LDAP_PASSWORD"]);
            
                $user = $this->ldap->query('dc=dcher,dc=local', '(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname='.$matricule.'))')->execute()->toArray();
                $connected = true;

                // Ajouter l'utilisateur au groupe
                $groupDn = "*group dn*";
                $query = $this->ldap->query($groupDn, "(objectclass=*)");
                $results = $query->execute();
                $groupEntry = $results[0];

                // Récupérer les membres actuels du groupe
                $members = $groupEntry->getAttribute('member');

                // Ajouter l'utilisateur au tableau des membres
                $members[] = $user[0]->getDn();

                // Définir les nouveaux membres du groupe
                $groupEntry->setAttribute('member', $members);
                // dd($groupEntry);
                
                $this->ldap->getEntryManager()->update($groupEntry);
```

Whereas with the AD console and the same user, I can add users to groups without problems. Other applications connect and modify the ldap without problems. It also works on the command line with ldapmodify.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

The problem is related to a limitation in the LDAP server that only allows a limited set of attributes to be modified at a time.

Instead of modifying the entire entry, I create a new entry with the same DN and only the attributes I want to modify, then update the entry with this new entry.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry;

// ...

// Ajouter l'utilisateur au groupe
$groupDn = "*groupdn*";
$query = $this->ldap->query($groupDn, "(objectclass=*)");
$results = $query->execute();
$groupEntry = $results[0];

// Récupérer les membres actuels du groupe
$members = $groupEntry->getAttribute('member');

// Ajouter l'utilisateur au tableau des membres
$members[] = $user[0]->getDn();

// Créer une nouvelle entrée avec le même DN et seulement l'attribut 'member' modifié
$newGroupEntry = new Entry($groupDn, ['member' => $members]);

// Mettre à jour l'entrée avec la nouvelle entrée
$this->ldap->getEntryManager()->update($newGroupEntry);
?>
```